# Terminal won't open on non-admin accounts in Sierra

Tags: terminal, macos, error

Terminal works just fine in my admin account, but won't open a terminal window in any of my regular user accounts.  If I choose Shell > New Window > New Window with Settings, I get the following "Internal error":

```
Exception Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Description: -[TTView touchBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde735b0710
User Info: (null)
```

macOS 10.12 Sierra

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences —> Parental Controls —> (select your Standard User Account) —> Allowed Apps
In the below list see whether terminal is allowed or not. if not just enable it.

Comment: Aadu, thanks for your answer.  I have parental controls disabled, so this is not the culprit.  It seems the terminal app opens ok but it can't open a window for some reason.

Comment: After opening up one terminal window , if you try opening another window by pressing cmd+n will it work ?